# How to improve slowness due to many @Inject in ManagedBean

Tags: jboss, wildfly, cdi

I am currently making a system based on an older system. The older system basically separates modules into separate classes and beans. However, for the new system, many modules are squeezed into one bean having it injecting so many classes and other beans making it very slow as it needs to initialize all the injected beans and classes.

Are there any ways I can improve this? Is there something like conditional injections where we only call the class when we need it?

Currently, what I have in mind is to only call classes when needed. E.g. when the user wants to access the User objects, only User related beans and classes are injected. Classes and beans related to Employer classes will not be called. I am not sure whether this is possible or not, if it's not, are there ways to improve the performance due to multiple injections?

Comment: For OpenWebBeans injected beans are instantiated the lazy way on access. Not sure if this is the case for wildfly CDI implementation.

Comment: So effectively a good design has been replaced by A Bad Design and now you want a workaround For A Bad Design ;-)

Comment: Bad Design means injecting multiple classes into one bean ? @Kukeltje

Comment: No, making a 'god' class (many modules (assuming one module contains multiple classes) into one class). And how many injections do you actually do? I cannot imagine you notice the injection of a dozen or even a couple of dozen beans. Unless you do a lot of work when the bean is created in e.g. a `@Postconstruct` annotated method. Then you maybe should implement things lazy in there

Comment: Hi @Selaron, may I know how OpenWebBeans lazily injects beans?

Comment: Without doing something special, as soon as the field annotated with `@Inject` is accessed and a method invoked on it, that bean gets Instantiated and its' `@PostConstruct` method executed if this is the first access time within the life span of theat beans' scope. I think they in fact inject Proxy instances that resolve beans and initialize on demand.

Comment: @Selaron Weld (reference CDI impl) is also lazy. How you do that is you always only inject proxies (for normal scoped beans! Dependent does not have proxy) and the actual bean instance beneath isnt created until needed. But this can still lead to a huge chain reaction creating all the beans at once. Though, like Kukeltje said, this actually smells of bad design.

Comment: Yes, I did find WeldContainer as one of the probable solutions but still unable to use it in codes due to some error. So you're saying using Weld also would not help to improve the performance due to injections ? @Siliarus

Comment: All I am saying is that both CDI impls are using lazy approach to resolution of normal scoped beans. And you already use Weld because that's CDI implementation used by WildFly (and pretty much all other EE servers except tomee). You would need to give us more gory details on what are you actually running to see what's the problem. I wonder how many beans you have there to see any actual performance issues with just injection...

Comment: Well, the JBOSS and WidlFly version is 8.2.0. Currently, the bean with performance issue has 30 injections. Many of the injections are heavy modules so it takes time to initialize. As I mentioned, this new system is based on an older system. So, instead of rewriting the codes, we injected the modules from the older system. However, different from the older system which separates modules, this new system requires multiple modules in one page.

Comment: If there are any suggestions or reads that you think might be helpful, please let me know. Currently, we see no other way than injecting those heavy modules.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using Instance interface. Instead of

```
@Inject
MyManagedBean myManagedBean
```

I used Instance to only inject the classes when it's used as so

```
@Inject
Instance<MyManagedBean> myManagedBean
```

So what this does is, everytime you want to call the class, you call it by .get() (e.g. myManagedBean.get()) and this will initialize the class. As long as the .get() is not called, the classes would not be initialized.

Comment: What strikes me as remarlable is that two experts say loading is in both implementations lazy by default but you only see a performance increase  when changing this. This leads me to think so,ething else is wrong in you code too. And, as suspected before, the injection is not the problem but e.g. construction (e.g. not using postconstruct or doing static thing or... ) without seeing actual code with performance numbers it is hard to understand what real problem (slow injection not being the real problem since that is quick otherwise many would have problems) is solved by this answer